# SQL Like condition fails to run

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been tasked to develop a query that behaves essentially like the following one:

```
SELECT * FROM tblTestData WHERE *.TestConditions LIKE '*textToSearch*'
```

The *textToSearch* is a string which contains information about the condition in which a given device is tested (Voltage, Current, Frequency, etc) in the following format as an example:

```
[V:127][PF:1][F:50][I:65]
```

The objective is to recover a list of any and all tests performed at a voltage of 127 Volts, so the SQL developed would look like the folllowing:

```
SELECT * FROM tblTestData WHERE *.TestConditions LIKE '*V:127*'
```

This works as intended but there is a problem due to an inproper introduction of data, there are cases in which the _textToSearch string looks like the following examples:

```
[V.127][PF:1][F:50][I:65]
[V.230][PF:1][F:50][I:65]
```

As you can see, my previous SQL transaction does not work as it does not meet the conditions.

If I try to do the following transaction with the objective of ignoring improper data format:

```
SELECT * FROM tblTestData WHERE *.TestConditions LIKE '*V*127*'
```

The transaction is not succesful and returns an error.

What am I doing wrong for this transaction not to work?  I am approaching this problem wrong?

I see a pair of problems although with this transaction, if there were a group of test conditions like the following:

```
[V.127][PF:1][F:50][I:127]
[V.230][PF:1][F:50][I:127]
```

Would it return the values of both points given that both meet the condition of the transaction stated above?

In conclusion, my questions are:

1. What is wrong with the LIKE '*V*127*' condition for it not to work?
2. What implications has working with this condition? Can it return more information than desired if I am not careful?

I hope it is clear what I am asking for, if it isn't, please point out what is not clear and I will try to clarify it

Comment: The wildcard for multiple characters is `%` in SQL, not `*`: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52142 but you probably want to use a regular expression: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One choice is to look for *any* character between the "V" and the "127":

```
WHERE TestConditions LIKE '%V_127%'
```

Note that `%` is the wildcard for a string of any length and `_` is the wildcard for a single character.

You can also use regular expressions:

```
WHERE regexp_like(TestConditions, 'V[.:]127')
```

Note that regular expressions match anywhere in the string, so wildcards at the beginning and end are not needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, although the other answers work as well, this one is what I was looking for, since it's very readable

Answer (score 1):

You could check for both cases (although this will decrease performance)

```
SELECT *
FROM tblTestData
WHERE (TestConditions LIKE '%V:127%' OR TestConditions LIKE '%V.127%')
```

It is better to clean the data in your database if only old records have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions is recommended by Oracle for this kind of conditions. You could build a regular expression for your case:

```
WITH your_table AS (
  SELECT '[V.127][PF:1][F:50][I:65]' text_to_search FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT '[V.230][PF:1][F:50][I:65]' text_to_search FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT '[V:127][PF:1][F:50][I:65]' text_to_search FROM dual
) 
SELECT *
FROM your_table 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(text_to_search,'\[V(.|:)127\]','i')
```

Or you could use the good old `LIKE` operator. In this case, you need to know that:

- `%` matches zero or more characters
- `_` matches only one character

So you should use an underscore to match the `:` or the `.`

```
WITH your_table AS (
  SELECT '[V.127][PF:1][F:50][I:65]' text_to_search FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT '[V.230][PF:1][F:50][I:65]' text_to_search FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT '[V:127][PF:1][F:50][I:65]' text_to_search FROM dual
) 
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE text_to_search LIKE '%V_127%';
```